# Легкая задачка по jquery

Tags: jquery

не работает эта строчка, помогите сделать ее))

```
  $("#label_text").css({color: "rgb(219, 133, 251)", text-shadow: "black 2px 2px 4px" })
```

Comment: Возможные причины:

- отсутствует элемент с id ``label_text``
- отсутствует точка с запятой после выражения
- попробуйте взять ``color`` и ``text-shadow`` в кавычки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по идее так

```
$("#label_text").css({"color": "rgb(219, 133, 251)", "text-shadow": "black 2px 2px 4px" });
```

нельзя задавать свойства объектам с "-"